# C++11 Range-based for loop for std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stdlist

If I understand the range-based for loop correctly, which expands

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

into

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
            __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

thus incrementing the pointer, and if I understand that `std::list`s are internally implemented as doubly linked lists, isn't it correct to assume that something like this would *not* print `0 1 2 3`, since the memory addresses are not sequential (implied by the `++__begin`)?

```
std::list<int> myList = {0, 1};
std::list<int> otherList = {10, 11};
myList.push_back(2);
myList.push_back(3);

for(auto& i: myList)
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

And yet it does print correctly. So then, is `std::list::iterator` overriding the behavior of the operators used in the range-for-loop expansion?

This is of particular importance to me if I choose to implement my own range-for iterable data structures.

Comment: _"...implement my own range-for iterable..."_ then you need to write an iterator implementation for your data structure(s) See here for the requirements placed on iterators: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator

Comment: You *do know* that a linked list is just about the *worst* performing data structure you can ask a modern CPU to work with - right? Take a hard look at `std::vector` ...

Comment: @Codesmith You missed the part of the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) where `begin_expr` and `end_expr` will resolve to the `begin()` and `end()` methods for a `std::list`: "*`begin_expr` and `end_expr` are defined as follows: ... If `range_expression` is an expression of a class type `C` that has both a member named `begin` and a member named `end` (regardless of the type or accessibility of such member), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`; ...*" The `begin()` and `end()` methods return **iterators**, not **pointers**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, iterators generally overload `++`, `*`, `->`, `==`, `!=` and sometimes `+ integral` and `--` and `- integral` and `<` etc, depending on ["iterator category"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories).

`std::list::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator, so overrides the first set of operators and only `--` from the second.

Iterators are not pointers.  On the other hand, pointers are both iterators, and the model upon which iterators where based.

Iterators that are fundamentally pointers are iterators into random access containers that store their data contiguously; vector, string, array and initializer_list.

Most of those still aren't raw pointers, but rather wrappers around the pointer.  This both permits some additional type safety and allows debug builds to do bounds checking and similar other checks.

Answer (score 6):

> thus incrementing the pointer

Nope, incrementing the *iterator*.

And a `std::list` iterator knows what to do… otherwise it would be useless and you wouldn't be able to do anything with your lists. :)

Only for contiguous data like vectors can an iterator be implemented as a basic pointer, though even then you'll often find that the iterator type is at least some kind of wrapper around pointers (e.g. in debug mode Visual Studio adds bounds checking).